# Pass drop down list into public function

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

im trying to pass a dropdownlist into a public function so that wherever I call this function for any dropdownlist it will work. I have multiple pages that have dropdownlists and i need it to be called many times.

i've declared it as such in my aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListVType" runat="server" 
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceVesselType" DataTextField="Vessel_Type" 
     DataValueField="VType_ID" Width="160px" AutoPostBack="True" 
     CausesValidation="True" OnDataBound="ddl_DataBound">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and in my cs

```
PublicFunctions pubvar = new PublicFunctions();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pubvar.ddl_DataBound(DropDownListVType);
}
```

and in the separate public functions class as:

```
public string ddl_DataBound(DropDownList d)
{
  return  d.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--- Please Select ---", String.Empty));
}
```

error im receiving are:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'

Comment: really new to all this. how to check that?

Comment: now it says the aspx file "

does not contain a definition for 'ddl_DataBound' and no extension method 'ddl_DataBound' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.frm_vessels_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Insert` returns void, so you cannot return that. Your function has a return type of `string`where it should have a return type of `void`:

```
public void ddl_DataBound(DropDownList d)
{
    d.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--- Please Select ---", String.Empty));
}
```

Comment: now it says the aspx file " does not contain a definition for 'ddl_DataBound' and no extension method 'ddl_DataBound' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.frm_vessels_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: That's because you use OnDataBound. That's an event. The name you put in there has to exist in your code-behind (it doesn't). Also, the event has a completely different signature.

Comment: ok so i've put in the PAGE LOAD  ddl_DataBound(DropDownListVType); in the CS FILE i've put protected void ddl_DataBound(DropDownList d)
        {
            pubvar.ddl_DataBound(d);
        }

now the error is  No overload for 'ddl_DataBound' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Comment: got it to work by putting thisi n the CS file protected void ddl_DataBound(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            pubvar.ddl_DataBound(DropDownListVType);
        } THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 1):

your return statement is the problem.

Please change your function to a void and remove the return.

```
public void ddl_DataBound(DropDownList d)
{
    d.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--- Please Select ---", String.Empty));
}
```

currently you try to return `Item.Insert()`'s return value (which is a void) as a string to the caller.

Comment: It's not trying to return the function, it's trying to return void. Also, it doesn't throw an exception, it's a compilation error.